# How does satellite TV get through in rain?

Tags: satellite

How does satellite TV get through in rain? I read somewhere that satellites make use of KU band to transmit data, we have heavy rainfall in various times of the year but even during those times TV channels run smoothly without problem. How is it possible? I thought microwaves are absorbed by water and can't penetrate through solid objects, higher the microwave frequency is. How do they travel through rain clouds and rain and finally into the dish antenna?

Comment: Vertical losses are a lot smaller than  horizontal losses thru rain.  obviously you are have lots of margin.

Answer (score 3):

According to this paper I found, http://licensing.fcc.gov/licensing.fcc.gov › myibfs › download, there is 3 dB loss allocated for rainfall in the downink direction for Ku band.  That's not very much compared to all the other losses in the link budget.  The fact that you don't see dropouts during rain just means that there is adequate margin to cover rainfall loss.